# MonoTouch Binding cannot use fields

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, pinvoke

Hello im trying to update google admboads to V6 but im having some trouble to bind the following and expose it to managed world

I have the following struct

```
typedef struct GADAdSize {
  CGSize size;
  NSUInteger flags;
} GADAdSize;
```

and I did this on monotouch side

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct GADAdSize
{
    public SizeF size;
    public uint flags;
}
```

I have the following code

```
extern GADAdSize const kGADAdSizeBanner;
extern GADAdSize const kGADAdSizeMediumRectangle;
```

I can't bind it using [Field] Attribute since docs specify that Field attribute can only be used for

- NSString references
- NSArray references
- 32-bit ints (System.Int32)
- 32-bit floats (System.Single)
- 64-bit floats (System.Double)

So I tried the following 2 ways i could think of

```
[DllImport ("__Internal")]
    extern static IntPtr kGADAdSizeMediumRectangle ();

public static GADAdSize MediumRectangle 
{
    get 
    {
        object obj = Marshal.PtrToStructure(kGADAdSizeMediumRectangle(), typeof(GADAdSize));
        return (GADAdSize) obj;
    }
}
```

and

```
public static GADAdSize Banner 
{
    get 
    {
        var handle = Dlfcn.dlopen ("libGoogleAdMobAds", 0);
        IntPtr ptr = Dlfcn.GetIntPtr(handle, "kGADAdSizeBanner");   
        Dlfcn.dlclose (handle);     
        object obj = Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(GADAdSize));
        return (GADAdSize) obj;
    }
}
```

And on both ways it crashes

Using the DLLImport I get a nullargument exception when calling Marshal.PtrToStructure() and the second one rises an  <strike>DLLNotFoundException</strike>  System.ArgumentNullException

Thanks in advance for any help

Alex

---

Edit:

Sorry @Poupou my bad, it throws a System.ArgumentNullException the handle value its 0 also the ptr value its 0

and the stacktrace is:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: src
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal:PtrToStructure (intptr,System.Type)
  at AlexTouch.GoogleAdMobAds.GADAdSizeConstants.get_Banner () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at MobclixText.MobclixTextViewController.ViewDidLoad () [0x00006] in /Users/Alex/Projects/MobclixText/MobclixText/MobclixTextViewController.cs:33
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging:void_objc_msgSend (intptr,intptr)
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIWindow.MakeKeyAndVisible () [0x00010] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIWindow.g.cs:98
  at MobclixText.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching (MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication app, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSDictionary options) [0x00031] in /Users/Alex/Projects/MobclixText/MobclixText/AppDelegate.cs:44
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0004c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:38
  at MobclixText.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /Users/Alex/Projects/MobclixText/MobclixText/Main.cs:17
```

I guess this is due to handle being 0.

About your comment

> Using dlsym with one of the special flags (man dlsym) might help.

Could you provide me an example on how to use it please =) ??

Alex

---

Edit 2:

Hello @Poupou and thanks for your answer, but with

```
IntPtr RTLD_MAIN_ONLY = (IntPtr) (-5);
IntPtr ptr = Dlfcn.GetIntPtr (RTLD_MAIN_ONLY, "kGADAdSizeBanner");
```

I still get `ptr` equals to `0` any other idea??

Alex

---

Edit 3:

Ok, im trying the following now

```
IntPtr RTLD_MAIN_ONLY = Dlfcn.dlopen (null, 0);
IntPtr ptr = Dlfcn.dlsym (RTLD_MAIN_ONLY, "kGADAdSizeBanner");              
Console.WriteLine("RTLD_MAIN_ONLY: " + RTLD_MAIN_ONLY);
Console.WriteLine("ptr: " + ptr);
```

`Dlfcn.dlopen (null, 0);` as its done [here](https://github.com/mono/maccore/blob/master/src/generator.cs#L2733) now I'm getting a handle value `-2` but I guess native linker it's removing the symbol now, how can I prevent this from happening??

Thanks a lot for your time @Poupou

Alex

Comment: *DLLNotFoundException* ? I'm surprised, what's the `handle` value ? and the stack trace? Since the library has been statically linked it won't be found. Using `dlsym` with one of the special flags (`man dlsym`) might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I found a way to get the values. The first part is to convince the linker to export the symbol (without hiding any existing ones). That can be done by creating an alias (which by default is global) of the (local) symbols. E.g.

```
-gcc_flags="-Xlinker -alias -Xlinker _kGADAdSizeBanner -Xlinker _MTAdSizeBanner"
```

Afterward the code:

```
IntPtr RTLD_MAIN_ONLY = Dlfcn.dlopen (null, 0);
IntPtr ptr = Dlfcn.dlsym (RTLD_MAIN_ONLY, "MTAdSizeBanner");
object obj2 = Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(GADAdSize));
```

will give you an instance of `GADAdSize` with a value of 320x50.

You'll need to re-export every symbol you need (yuck) but that should be possible to include this in the `[LinkWith]` attribute (iirc) so it won't be a requirement for end users.

Comment: Will try it tonight and let you know if that worked ;-) thanks a lot sebastien

Comment: Thanks Thanks Thanks a lot Sebastien that worked you are my hero ;-) just asked another thing in the bug report hope you can help me. thanks again

Comment: @poupou I have the same problem but with dynamic library. any suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Your second solution is what is *normally* used. It dynamically loads the symbols from the specified *library*. OTOH this works **only** for system libraries on iOS.

Why ? because your own supplied libraries will be linked statically with your main executable. That's the same reason that `[DllImport("__Internal")` must be used for normal p/invoke.

Back to symbols, `dldym` has some options to work on the main executable (or all loaded code). Do a `man dlsym` on a terminal window to see them. That might (did not try it) work using:

```
 IntPtr RTLD_MAIN_ONLY = (IntPtr) -5;
 IntPtr ptr = Dlfcn.GetIntPtr (RTLD_MAIN_ONLY, "kGADAdSizeBanner");
```

Note 1: `Dlfcn.GetIntPtr` is an utility method that basically wraps `dlsym`;

Note2: look at the other options as well :-) If you get a non-null (not `IntPtr.Zero`) pointer then you can try to marshal it into a `SizeF` structure.

Comment: First ensure that the symbol is included in your main (native) executable (i.e. that the native linker did not remove it, otherwise nothing will work) and then read `man dlsym` for the other special values.

Comment: Ok, so in order to get a handle of my main executable, should i use `var handle = Dlfcn.dlopen ("__Internal", 0);` ? Sorry I'm new to this tools

Comment: ok, tried `Dlfcn.dlopen (null, 0);` as its done here `https://github.com/mono/maccore/blob/master/src/generator.cs#L2733` now I'm getting a handle value `-2` but I guess native linker it's removing the symbol, how can I prevent this from happening??

Comment: Project settings. It will be quicker (and simpler if you can fill a bug report and we can look at your project.