# Expose 'kFirebaseServerValueTimestamp' from a iOS binding project and example to use it

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, firebase

I am trying to use the firebase ios sdk in a monotouch project. 
I have a scenario where i need to set the value of a property in firebase to the firebase server timestamp. Now how do i achieve the following:

1. Expose the kFirebaseServerValueTimestamp constant in firebase.h from my iOS binding project
2. How do i use it from c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very similar to [MonoTouch Binding cannot use fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525043/monotouch-binding-cannot-use-fields)

The answer indicates that you can expose some constants by correctly instructing the compiler.

But in the end, it's a constant, and as such you can hardcode it's value in your binding as well.